# How do I remove a forwarded port in Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, port

I downloaded a Vagrantfile and am running it on my CentOS 7 box. When I execute `vagrant up`, the process starts successfully  and the machine is booted and ready. I'm able to access the process using the URL:

```
http://<IP_ADDRESS_OF_BOX>:8080
```

However, I don't want Vagrant to use port 8080 and would rather use an obscure port like 8601. So, I modified the Vagrantfile to include another entry for `config.vm.network`.

Before change - Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = 'ToraToraTora'
end
```

After change - Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = 'ToraToraTora'
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8601
end
```

Now I'm able to access the process using the new port:

```
http://<IP_ADDRESS_OF_BOX>:8601
```

However, the previous port continues to work too:

```
http://<IP_ADDRESS_OF_BOX>:8080
```

Executing `sudo netstat -tulpn`:

```
[ToraToraTora@andromeda ~]$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 26206
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2222          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26206/VBoxHeadless  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26206/VBoxHeadless  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8601            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26206/VBoxHeadless  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40168           0.0.0.0:*                           26206/VBoxHeadless  
[ToraToraTora@andromeda ~]$
```

Output from running `vagrant port`:

```
[ToraToraTora@andromeda app]$ vagrant port
The forwarded ports for the machine are listed below. Please note that
these values may differ from values configured in the Vagrantfile if the
provider supports automatic port collision detection and resolution.

    22 (guest) => 2222 (host)
    80 (guest) => 8080 (host)
    80 (guest) => 8601 (host)
[ToraToraTora@andromeda app]$
```

How do I stop the Vagrant process from using port 8080 and ONLY use port 8601?

Comment: So a `vagrant reload` is not clearing the old forwarded port? What is the output of the `vagrant port` command?  https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/port.html

Comment: It's odd as vagrant doesn't appear to take the parameter of "port". I have Vagrant version 1.7.4 installed.

Comment: Right, that command was added in 1.8.0. You should install the latest which is 1.8.1 as I write this.

Comment: Updated the question with output from "vagrant port"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could explicitly disable the 8080 forwarded port...

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = 'ToraToraTora'
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8601
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, disabled: true
end
```

If you make that change and do a `vagrant reload`, it will clear the 8080 forwarded port. At that point, you can remove the 8080 line from your Vagrantfile.

**NOTE:** Port forwarding in Vagrant can be compared to radio broadcasts. Guest ports are like radio stations while host ports are like radios. In the same way that a radio station can broadcast to any number of radios, a guest port on the Vagrant machine can be forwarded to multiple ports on the host machine. However, each host port can only receive forwarded traffic from one guest port at a time in the same way that a radio can only be tuned to one station at a time.

So in this case, two radios (ports 8601 and 8080 on the host) were tuned to the same station (port 80 on the guest). The solution was simply to switch off the radio at 8080.

Comment: Worked like a charm !! Thanks for the note.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.

Comment: Added a note about how port forwarding works in Vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

if you are able to use `http://<IP_ADDRESS_OF_BOX>` it sounds to me you're using [vagrant private network](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html) with a static IP, in such case, all ports are accessible on the IP and you do not necessarily need the `forward_port` option.

Also when `netstat` with your options run it with `sudo netstat -tulpn` so you'll find the PID/Program Name behind

Comment: Edited the question with results from running netstat with sudo.

Comment: Yes, there was NO forwarding of Port to begin with and I made the entry to forward to port 8601. However, the question still remains: How do I stop the Vagrant process from using the port 8080, and ONLY use the forwarded port 8601.

Comment: can you open virtual box and check for this VM the network port and try to remove the 8080 - run `vagrant reload` and make sure this forwarding does not come back

Comment: In the VirtualBox VM folder I modified the xxxxx.vbox file to delete the entry for "<Forwarding name="tcp8080" proto="1" hostport="8080" guestport="80"/>". However, upon reload the entry is created again.